# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() unpacking Facebook array in Laravel 4

Tags: arrays, facebook, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to store the FBIDs of a Facebook user's friends in the column of a mysql database.  I've tried looking up other answer on this issue, and I have tried to implement it (in Laravel 4).  Here is what I have done:

In the Facebook.php file, one of the providers:

```
'friends'  => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='.$token->access_token
```

In my Oauth2 Controller:

```
 $friends_list = $user['friends'];
 $friends_list_array  = json_decode($friends_list,true);
 $arr= $friends_list_array['data'];
 $friend_ids_arr = array();
 foreach($arr as $friend) {
   $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
 }
 $friend_ids = implode("," , $friend_ids_arr);
```

And then I want to store the $friend_ids object in a "text" column in my database.  However, when running this, I keep getting the error:  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

But it is very clearly being supplied an array as it should.  Is there something I'm not seeing?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the returned result is a `json`, the returned object should look something like this

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxx", 
    "name": "Sheikh Heera", 
    "friends": {
        "data": [
            { "name": "RaseL KhaN", "id": "xxx" },
            { "name": "Yizel Herrera", "id": "xxx" }
        ], 
        "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/friends?limit=..."
        }
    }
}
```

After you `json_decode`

```
$user = json_decode($user, true);
```

It should look something like

```
Array
(
    [id] => xxxxxxx
    [name] => Sheikh Heera
    [friends] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => RaseL KhaN
                        [id] => xxx
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Yizel Herrera
                        [id] => xxx
                    )

            )

        [paging] => Array
            (
                [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/friends?limit=...
            )

    )

)
```

So, now you can

```
 $friends_list = $user['friends'];
 $data = $friends_list['data'];
```

Make sure your `$data` array is not empty and then loop

```
if(count($data)) {
    $friend_ids_arr = array();
    foreach($data as $friend) {
        $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
    }
}
```

So, the `foreach` will run only when `$data` has items in it.

**Update:** It may help you

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,friends&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$friends = $contents['friends'];
$friend_ids_arr[]
foreach($friends['data'] as $friend)
{
    $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
}
```

Comment: Then make sure that `$user['friends']` not empty, try `var_dump($user['friends'])`.

Comment: It is definitely not empty, it is just returning a url.  So if I go to the graph url with the associated access token, it lists out the whole thing.  How do I get just the data portion from the graph ulr?

Comment: It still says:

Illegal string offset 'data' referencing the $data = $friends_list['data'];
 line

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the returned result ?

Comment: it just puts an error on the page saying llegal string offset 'data'

Comment: `var_dump($friends_list)`, it'll work before you access `data`.

Comment: friends_list is just the print out of that url: 

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id&access_token=*large token*  (it is output as a string)

Comment: You should make a `GET` request using this `url`.

Comment: So store the url, and then make a GET request in a view when I want to pull specific friend IDs?

Comment: Yes, this `url` will give you the data.

Comment: You can also use `$content = file_get_contents($url);`.